# Parallel MPI Version

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi, dot-product

I have to write a parallel MPI version of my dot product (code below):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#define SIZE 10000000

volatile float a[SIZE];
volatile float b[SIZE];

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  long int       i;
  double         sum;
  struct timeval time1, time2;

  srand(time(0));
  
  for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
  {
    a[i] = rand();
    b[i] = rand();
  }
    
  gettimeofday(&time1, 0);
  
  sum = 0.0;
  
  for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
  {
    sum = sum + a[i]*b[i];
  }

  gettimeofday(&time2, 0);
MPI_Scatter(a, 1, MPI_INT, &b, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  printf("Elapsed time (us) = %d\n", (time2.tv_sec-time1.tv_sec)*1000000 + time2.tv_usec - time1.tv_usec);

  return 0;
}
```

**My question is**, what code do I need to add to the program, what MPI primitives are useful?

Comment: `MPI_Scatter()` or `MPI_Scatterv()` and `MPI_Reduce()`

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, thanks for helping. I've edited the post. I've been trying to work on it for hours now. But I can't get the arguments to work, and could you give me a hint where the MPI_Scatter should be placed?

Comment: Why don't you tell me how you want to parallelize the dot product in plain English first?